# Is a member initializer list part of the declaration or the definition of a constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, member-initialization, ctor-initializer

Please explain how to use member initializer lists.
I have a class declared in a `.h` file and a `.cpp` file like this:

```
class Example
{
private:
    int m_top;
    const int m_size;
    /* ... */
public:
    Example(int size, int grow_by = 1) : m_size(5), m_top(-1);
    /* ... */
    ~Example();
};
```

I'm initializing `m_size` on object creation because of `const`. How should I write the constructor?
Should I repeat `: m_size(5), m_top(-1)`, or I can omit this step?

```
Example::Example(int size, int grow_by)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

or

```
Example::Example(int size, int grow_by) : m_size(5), m_top(-1)
{
    /* ... some code here */
}
```

Comment: You specify the initialization list when you define the constructor, not when you declare it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This is the initializer list:

```
Example::Example( int size, int grow_by) : m_size(5), m_top(-1)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

and it should be done only in the `.cpp` file.

If you did it in the header like in your example, you would get an error.

Comment: Note that the order of initialization should be the same as the order of declaration, else, it gives a warning (compiled with `[-Weffc++]`).

Answer (score 65):

Just to clarify something that came up in some of the other answers...

**There is no requirement that the initializer list be in either the source (.cpp) or header (.h) file.**  In fact, the compiler does not distinguish between the two types of files.  The important distinction is between the contructor's [declaration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_declaration) and it's definition. The initializer list goes with the definition, not the declaration.

Usually, the declaration is in a header file and the definition is in a source file, however, this is not a requirement of the language (i.e. it will compile).
It is not unusual to provide constructor definitions inline in the class declaration when the constructor is empty or short. In that case, an initializer list would go inside the class declaration, which would probably be in a header file.

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass(int value) : m_value(value)
    {}
private:
    int m_value;
};
```

Comment: Note: some frameworks and languages like Qt's C++ require their classes and structs derived from `QObject` to use their own header for leveraging their `Q_OBJECT` macro to properly take advantage of its potential.

Answer (score 15):

The member initializer list should be a part of the constructor definition in the source file.
Write this in the `.cpp` file:

```
Example(int size, int grow_by) : m_size(5), m_top(-1)
{
    /* ... */
}
```

The header file should only have:

```
Example(int size, int grow_by = 1);
```

The header file only declares the constructor, the member initializer list is not a part of the declaration.

Comment: I.e. initialiser list only goes into constructor definition.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Oh a bit late just had it edited before your comment :P

Comment: I think the `= 1` default parameter should only be in the header, not the `cpp` file.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Correct! Ah err `cntrl + c`, `cntrl + v` Bad habit :P!

Comment: Additionally, data members are initialized in the order they are declared, so it is good practice to order your initializer list in the same way to be consistent. In your example, that would be `: m_top(-1), m_size(5)`. See  [Effective C++](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html) by Meyers, Item 4.

Answer (score 9):

Adding to others answers, the one most important thing one should remember about the initializer list is that:

> the order of initialization is decided in the order in which the data members are declared, not the the order in which you have initialized the data members using initialization list

Consider your example:

```cpp
class Example
{
private:
    int m_top;
    const int m_size;
    /* ... */
public:
    Example(int size, int grow_by = 1) : m_size(5), m_top(-1) {}
    /* m_size appears to be initialized with a value first,
     * but m_top is initialized to the value -1 before
     * m_size is initialized to 5. */
    
    /* ... */
    ~Example(){}
};
```

If one is not aware of the above, it has very serious implications.

Comment: Many compilers will warn about initialization order if it looks like there might be an ambiguity that could cause problems.  You should enable such warnings if they are not and pay attention to such warnings.

Comment: Yes but still worth enough to know what the warning is really about :)

Answer (score 1):

In C++11 you can use [non-static data member initialization](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2008/n2756.htm).  This is especially useful if you have several constructors that need a common value for a member variable.

```
class Example
{
private:
    int m_top = -1;
    const int m_size = 5;
    ...
public:
    Example ( int size, int grow_by = 1 );
    ...
    ~Example();
};

...

Example::Example( int size, int grow_by )
{
    ... some code here
}
```

You can override the value in a constructor if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have an initializer list both in the header and the source file. The list should be in whichever file defines your constructor. Also you must include a body when defining the constructor, even if it's empty.

On a side note, you should only specify the default arguments in the function prototype, not in the definition.