# Set my window in a class c++

Tags: c++, sfml

I don't know why but I'm getting an error when creating my window in a class.

The error is:

`game.cpp(11): error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 2 arguments`

I'm not understanding the cause of this, the responsible is in the constructor for the class :

`window.cpp`

```
Application::Application(std::map<string,string>& s, std::map<string, string>& t){

settings = s;
theme = t;
window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test"); //error is here

}
```

In my header `window.h` is set up in private as:

```
private:
    std::map<string, string> settings;
    std::map<string, string> theme;
    sf::RenderWindow window;
```

My `main.cpp` sets it up like so:

```
Application game(setting,style);
```

What could be the cause of this ?

Comment: Use member initializers to initialize your members.

Comment: @chris You mean `Application something(input,input);` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use member initializers to initialize your members :

```
Application::Application(std::map<string,string>& s, std::map<string, string>& t)
:settings(s),
 theme(t),
 window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600), "Test") 
{
}
```

It’s called a member initializer list.The member initializer list consists
of a comma-separated list of initializers preceded by a colon. It’s placed after the closing
parenthesis of the argument list and before the opening bracket of the function body.

Comment: Wait why is it outside the curly brackets ? Ive done it via my question method up until now it used to work.. whats different about that method o_0

Comment: can be useful link.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711990/what-is-this-weird-colon-member-syntax-in-the-constructor