# Is it required to define the initialization list in a header file?

Tags: c++, initialization-list

Recently I created class `Square`:

=========header file======

```
class Square
{
    int m_row;
    int m_col;

public:
    Square(int row, int col): m_row(row), m_col(col) 
};
```

==========cpp file======

```
#include "Square.h"

Square::Square(int row, int col)
{
    cout << "TEST";
}
```

but then I receive lots of errors. If I remove the cpp file and change the header file to:

=========header file======

```
class Square
{
    int m_row;
    int m_col;

public:
    Square(int row, int col): m_row(row), m_col(col) {};
};
```

it complies with no errors. Does it mean that initialization list must appear in the header file?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You can have

==============header file ================

```
class Square
{
    int m_row;
    int m_col;

public:
    Square(int row, int col);
};
```

==================cpp ====================

```
Square::Square(int row, int col):m_row(row), m_col(col) 
{}
```

Comment: doesn't _explain_ the problem and why this fixes it.

Comment: @underscore_d initialization list is part of **definition** so you have to put list in place where definition/body/ **{}** is used

Answer (score 84):

***Initialization list*** is part of constructor's *definition* so you need to define it at the same place you define constructor's body.
This means that you can have it either in your header file:

```
public:
    Square(int row, int col): m_row(row), m_col(col) {};
```

or in .cpp file:

```
Square::Square(int row, int col) : m_row(row), m_col(col) 
{
    // ...
}
```

but when you have definition in .cpp file, then in header file, there should be only its declaration:

```
public:
    Square(int row, int col);
```

Comment: You should remove the extra semicolon from the first code example.

Comment: This seems to better answer the question.

Answer (score 12):

The initialization list appears with the constructor definition, not with a declaration that isn't a definition. So, your options are either:

1. *define* ctor in the class definition (in the header file):

```
Square(int row, int col): m_row(row), m_col(col) {}; // ctor definition
```

2. declare ctor in the class definition (in the header file):

```
Square(int row, int col); // ctor declaration
```

...and define elsewhere (usually in the .cpp file):

```
Square::Square(int row, int col): m_row(row), m_col(col) {} // ctor definition
```

"Elsewhere" is allowed to be in the header, if you make it `inline`.

Answer (score 3):

Not a requirement. It can be implemented in a source file as well.

```
// In a source file
Square::Square(int row, int col): m_row(row), 
                                  m_col(col) 
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of initializing a variable called member initialization list. Member initialization list can be used in header file or source file. That doesn't matter. But the constructor must have definition when you initialize it in header file. You can refer [C++ Member Initialization List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list) for more details.