# Having another class as a class member in C++

Tags: c++, class, constructor

I am trying refactor a piece of C++ code into a class. Right now the code looks like this

```
USB Usb;
ACMAsyncOper AsyncOper;
ACM Acm(&Usb, &AsyncOper);
```

I want to move this code into the constructor of a class. Also I want to have the variables `Usb`, `AsyncOper` and `Acm` as member variables of the class.

I wrote it as the following

```
// eZ430.h

class eZ430
{
    public:
        eZ430();    
    private:
        USB Usb;
        ACMAsyncOper AsyncOper;
        ACM Acm;
};


// eZ430.cpp
#include "eZ430.h"

eZ430::eZ430() {
    USB Usb;
    ACMAsyncOper AsyncOper;
    ACM Acm(&Usb, &AsyncOper);
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I am very new to C++ and can't get it to work.

Kindly let me know how to implement it. Thanks.

**Edit**: When I have the following code in the constructor

```
eZ430::eZ430() {
    USB Usb;
    ACMAsyncOper AsyncOper;
    ACM Acm(&Usb, &AsyncOper);
}
```

I get the error `error: expected identifier before '&' token`

And when I change it to

```
eZ430::eZ430() {
    USB Usb;
    ACMAsyncOper AsyncOper;
    ACM Acm(&Usb, &AsyncOper);
}
```

I get the error `no matching function for call to 'ACM::ACM()'`

Comment: Are you getting any errors? Tell us what they are.

Comment: What you want to do -- have objects as member variables of another class -- is *in general* possible, but there may be things about the classes involved that make it not work.  Also, you definitely shouldn't be redeclaring all your data members as local variables inside the constructor.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Updated the question with the error that I am getting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your constructor should initialize `Acm` through its *member-initializer* list:

```
eZ430() : Acm(&Usb, &AsyncOper)
{}
```

We do this because `ACM` doesn't have a default constructor, and we have to make sure that default-construction of `eZ430` causes the specialized-construction of `Acm`.

And leave the body empty as there is no reason to recreate the `Usb` and `AsyncOper` data-members inside the constructor. Besides, doing `ACM Acm(&Usb, &AsyncOper)` potentially causes Undefined Behavior because you're accessing the addresses of local variables that will go out of scope when the constructor body closes. If you use those addresses elsewhere that will cause the Undefined Behavior.

Related: [C++ Member Initialization List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list)

Comment: To elaborate further, I'm guessint Acm doesn't have a default constructor. That's why the member-initializer is necessary.

Comment: Not only is there no reason to recreate the data members inside the constructor, it's actively wrong: the data members wind up being default-initialized, or worse, initialized with pointers to locals which immediately go out of scope, thus arming an undefined-behavior bomb.