# Use the parent class's function with the same name and aruments

Tags: c++, class

I have the following classes:

```
class CPolygon
{
  SPolygon* data; // will be populated by constructor
  // ... members here ...
public:
  CPolygon();
  CPolygon(int type);
  SPolygon getData(int index);
  // ... methods here ...
};

class CSquare : public CPolygon
{
  // ... members here ...
public:
  CSquare();
  SSquare getData(int index);
  // ... methods here ...
};
```

The second `CPolygon()` constructor accepts the type of polygon you want.

Is there a way to call this (second) constructor on `CSquare()` constructor passing the value for square type, like:

```
CSquare::CSquare()
{
  CPolygon(TYPE_SQUARE);
}
```

to make data that are square?

**EDIT**

I added new member and method/function. This is the structure (and union):

```
union SPolygon
{
  SHead   head;
  SSquare square;
  // ... more structure here ...
}

struct SSquare
{
  SHead head;
  // ... more membere here ...
}
```

I want to return the square data:

```
SSquare CSquare::getData(int index)
{
  return getData(index).square;
}
```

But the `getData()` (inside the function) is considered as `CSquare`'s but I need it to be `CPolygon`'s. How?

Comment: For your edited question, please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an [*member initialization list*](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/initialization-lists-c++.html):

```
CSquare::CSquare(): CPolygon(TYPE_SQUARE) {}
```

This invokes `CPolygon`'s constructor first, according to the correct type, then the `CSquare()` constructor body is executed.

*Note*: Initialization lists apply not only to super-classes, but also to ordinary class members. For examples, please refer to [C++ Member Initialization List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list).

For your edited question, use `CPolygon::getData` to call the specified version of `getData`:

```
SSquare CSquare::getData(int index)
{
  return CPolygon::getData(index).square;
}
```