# Basic c++ constructor notation

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm learning c++ and I was looking at the following webpage:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384842.aspx

The code given on that page contains the following line of code under step 7.

```
Cardgame::Cardgame(int players)
    : players(players)
{
    totalParticipants += players;
    cout << players << " players have started a new game.  There are now "
          << totalParticipants << " players in total." << endl;
}
```

As I understand it, the first line corresponds to an object constructor which takes a single integer argument. However, I don't understand the line directly after it

```
: players(players)
```

What does this notation mean? Could someone please explain this to me in as simple a way as possible?

Comment: It's the initialization of a class member variable. Lookup constructor initializer lists.

Answer (score 1):

It is called `member initialization list`. You may find this thread [C++ member initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list) useful.

In the code you posted, it will initialize the class member `players` with the input value `players`. (BTW, bad style to use the same names).

Answer (score 1):

It is called the *member-initialization-list*.

It is used to initialize members of a class by choosing the best initializer for it. Here you are initializing your member `players` with the parameter of the same. (It can be confusing to choose the same name, it is not a really good practice.)

From the standard :

> **12.6.2 Initializing bases and members [class.base.init]**
>
> In the deﬁnition of a constructor for a class, initializers for direct and virtual base subobjects and non-static data members can be speciﬁed by a ctor-initializer, which has the form
>
> ```
> ctor-initializer:
>     mem-initializer-list
>
> mem-initializer-list:
>     mem-initializer ...opt
>     mem-initializer , mem-initializer-list ...opt
>
> mem-initializer:
>     mem-initializer-id ( expression-listopt)
>     mem-initializer-id braced-init-list
>
> mem-initializer-id:
>     class-or-decltype
>     identifier
> ```

**I really suggest you to read the first post of this thread who explain it very well by quoting *Scott Meyers* : http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/17820/**

You can get more informations here :http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: Kudos for bringing in the Meyers' notes!

Answer (score 0):

This refers to `initialization list` which is another form of initialising the members of an object.

Advantage of initialization list over normal construction is that it usually fast as it doesn't create a temporary object before initializing the members.

And a disadvantage could be that `this` pointer is to be used a bit carefully in initialization list

Answer (score 0):

As it's already mentioned by taocp, the line refers to member initialization list.

There are couple of ways to initialize members
1. member initialization list (efficient approach)
2. using assignment e.g. players = 10

It might not make any difference for built-in types e.g. int, char
but if you are assigning big objects then use member initialization list. Constructor/ Destructor gets called in assignment which is definitely not warranted