# Define an empty constructor in c++

Tags: c++

In main.cpp

```
LLC* llc = new LLC();
```

Here is the constructor in llc.cpp

```
LLC::LLC() :
{
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
}
```

Here is the error that I get:

```
llc.cpp(36): error: expected an identifier
{
^
```

What mistake am I making?
The constructor is given in the public section of the class LLC in the header file of llc.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
LLC::LLC() :
{
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
}
```

should be

```
LLC::LLC()
{
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are specifying the [Member Initializing List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list) in your constructor by adding a `:`. That's why the compiler is expecting an identifier there. You should remove the `:` if you do not intend to initialize any members there.

```
LLC::LLC() // Absense of :
{
    cout<<"test"<<endl;
}
```