# Parameters to use in a referenced function c++

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

I am very confused as to what kind of variables I would put into my function here: *names*. I am doing a practice problem in a C++ book, because I am learning C++ and am on References and pointers right now, and cannot find a solution.

Just for background information, the problem asks:

> Write a function that prompts the user to enter his or her first name and last name, as two separate values.
>   This function should return both values to the caller via additional pointer(or reference) parameters that are passed to the function.
>   Try doing this first with pointers and then with references.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <istream>

using namespace std;

struct someStruct{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
};

void names(someStruct &firstname, someStruct &lastname) {
    cout << "First Name: " << "\n";
    cin >> firstname.firstname;
    cout << "Last Name: " << "\n";
    cin >> lastname.lastname;
    // I was just curious is adding firstname to firstname would work... and     it did
    cout << lastname.lastname << ", " << firstname.firstname;
    cin.get();
}

int main() {
    names();
    // I don't know what to put here, above, as parameters
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Do you know how to do it if `names()` took pointers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code makes no sense, why are you passing `someStruct` twice?

For the *reference* part, you should have something like:

```
void names(someStruct &s) { // <<<< Pass struct once as a reference
    cout << "First Name: " << "\n";
    cin >> s.firstname;
    cout << "Last Name: " << "\n";
    cin >> s.lastname;
}
```

and in `main()`:

```
int main() {
    someStruct x; // <<<< Create an instance of someStruct
    names(x); // <<<< Pass it as parameter

    cout << "Input was: firstName = " << x.firstname 
         << ", lastName = " << x.lastname 
         << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

---

For the *pointer* part, you should have something like:

```
void names(someStruct *s) { // <<<< Pass struct once as a reference
    cout << "First Name: " << "\n";
    cin >> s->firstname;
         // ^^ Note the difference in dereferencing
    cout << "Last Name: " << "\n";
    cin >> s->lastname;
         // ^^ Note the difference in dereferencing
}
```

and in `main()`:

```
int main() {
    someStruct x; // <<<< Create an instance of someStruct
    names(&x); // <<<< Pass the address of x as parameter
       // ^ Note the addess-of operator here

    cout << "Input was: firstName = " << x.firstname 
         << ", lastName = " << x.lastname 
         << endl;
    cin.get();
}
```

Comment: Ohh, I did not think about it that way. Thank you.

Comment: Also, I thought that whenever you set parameters that involved references, in a function, that they had to point to an initialized value. Or, does setting the parameter, initialize the value? I am confused on how this function works, when it is referencing to a value that isn't initialized anywhere else. An explanation would help.

Comment: @MaxKhan Values are initialized by the compiler generated default constructor of `someStruct` using the default constructors for the contained member variables (`std::string::string()` for your case => empty `string`), unless you define a default constructor yourself, and initialize them using the [_member initializer list_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list).