# C++ Inheritance and the Colon syntax used on field variable question

Tags: c++

for the code snippet below, what does the colon in the line `Node(int elt = 0,Node * p = NULL):data(elt),next(p){}` do exactly? From what I've searched, it seems the colon used is the inheritance syntax, but in this case, I assume `Node(int elt = 0,Node * p = NULL)` is a constructor for the Node structure, and it's inheriting or perhaps accessing the `data(elt)` field variable? But `data` is a primitive data type, why is there a parameter "elt" inside of it?
I'll appreciate it very much if anyone can explain the concepts. Thanks.

```
class List{
  public:
    void addAt(int pos, int elt);
    void delAll(int x);
  private:
    struct Node{
      int data;
      Node * next;
      Node(int elt = 0,Node * p = NULL):data(elt),next(p){}
  };
};
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list).