# What does a function inheriting from a private variable mean (C++)?

Tags: c++, function, class, poco-libraries

I have come across a few examples while researching the Poco Net library, and have no clue what this is called, or why it is even used:

```cpp
class TestClass {
  public:
    TestClass() : _length(0){}
  private:
    int _length;
```

I've got 2 questions about this:

1. How is the function inheriting from a variable, and
2. why does the variable have a parameter (0)?

Thank you.

Comment: This is a [member-initialization-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list)

Comment: you can not inherit functions, the ':' notation is used in the constructors to pass parameters.

Comment: thank you cigien and tstoev!