# Could someone explain or identify this sintax?

Tags: c++

I was reading Peter Shirley's [Ray Tracing in One Weekend](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html) when I found this in one of his code's classes: `vec3() : e{0,0,0} {}`

I've searched for a while and I think this is [Singleton pattern](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/singleton/cpp/example), but I may be wrong.
Can anyone tell me what is this sintax? It would also be helpful if you could tell why is the last `{}` necessary.

Here's a bigger snippet of the code:

```
#define VEC3_H

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

using std::sqrt;

class vec3 {
    public:
        vec3() : e{0,0,0} {}
        vec3(double e0, double e1, double e2) : e{e0, e1, e2} {}
```

The full header file is too big to put here, but you can find it on [chapter 3.1 of the book](https://raytracing.github.io/books/RayTracingInOneWeekend.html#thevec3class/variablesandmethods)

Comment: Are you asking about [member initializer list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list) `: e{...}`? The last `{}` is the (empty) body of the constructor.

Comment: [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor)

Comment: That and the use of ```:``` between ```vec3()``` and ```e{...}{}```
I've read the link and this seems to be explained as well, thanks for the quick respose