# My positive double value is printed as a negative output like -6.27744e+66

Tags: c++, output, double

I get a negative output to a positive double variable.
My object is: Fahrzeug fr("BMW",200.45);

```
 class Fahrzeug {
    private:
    string p_sName;
        double p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit;
    public:
        Fahrzeug(string p_sName, double p_dMaxgeschwindigkeit) {
            this->p_sName = p_sName; 
            this->p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit = p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit; //the output is negative
            cout << "Der Name des Fahrzeugs: " << this->p_sName << "\n" << "Die maximale Geschwindigkeit des Fahrzeugs: " << this->p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit << endl;
            }
    };
        #endif /* FAHRZEUG_H_*/
```

Comment: This is a typo. Although it wont help detect this type of problem, prefer a initializer list: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list)

Comment: C++ is case sensitive, and you have a typo based on case of names.   So you're initialising an uninitialised variable with itsself - which causes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this->p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit = p_dMaxGeschwindigkeit;` this assigns the (uninitialised) member variable to itself.

You also have a parameter called `p_dMaxgeschwindigkeit` which you probably meant to use but note that its not the same spelling - it has a lowercase `G` and C++ is case sensitive.