# Constructor Initializing list in C++

Tags: c++

I had a question on the following C++ code. Can someone explain the constructor initialization list because I don't understand why we are saying x(a) like its a function? Also in the main, why are they using b(10) and not x?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base{
  int x;
public:
  Base(int a):x(a) {}
};

int main() {
  Base b(10);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Related: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665021/c-member-initialization-list)

Comment: In the initializer list you use `<member variable name>(<constructor parameters>)`;  When declaring a variable you use `<variable type> <variable name>(<constructor parameters>);` note that the syntax is pretty similar; in the initializer list just the type is missing, since it's determined in some other place...

Comment: Better read https://www.amazon.com/C-Programming-Language-4th/dp/0321563840

Comment: `I don't understand why we are saying x(a) like its a function?` no x(a) is not a function but one of several different ways of initialization. With that said I think it is good that you recognize this looking like a function as this problem will come up as your code gets more complicated.

Comment: They are using b(10) because they decided to name the `Base` variable `b`. I would have probably written `Base base(10);` as its a bad practice to use 1 letter variable names that are not loop index values. Your variable and function names should be descriptive of the purpose of the variable or function.

Comment: This is explained in any **beginner level C++ book** listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).